# What is <noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript> in an NextJS app

Tags: javascript, next.js, metadata

Learning NextJS, I'm up to [adding metadata](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/assets-metadata-css/polishing-layout). After completing the steps in that lesson, in the front-end source code I see

`<noscript id="__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"></noscript>`

What is it for, and what produces it?

A Google search doesn't display much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just Googled it and the second result explains what it's for: https://dev.to/omher/building-react-app-with-module-federation-and-nextjsreact-1pkh
It's apparently simply a marker for Next to know where in the document to insert the CSS.

The reason it is an empty `noscript` tag is to make it basically invisible in the DOM and doesn't risk interfering with your page.

Comment: I've also Googled it and this questions was the first result, so please don't mind other people asking questions

Comment: @BohdanYurov As you can imagine, this question was not the first result five months ago when it was just asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Each next application should contains this tag   , So that next application can find this tag and render all necessary css's below that tag

Look at the below snippet , this will be available in nextjs build files ,

```html
function App_App() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/index_js_default().createElement(index_js_.Suspense, {
    fallback: 'loading...'
  }, /*#__PURE__*/index_js_default().createElement("noscript", {
    id: "__next_css__DO_NOT_USE__"
  }), /*#__PURE__*/index_js_default().createElement(MyApplication, null));
}
```

Also you can find this tag by entering this in browser console **$('#**next_css__DO_NOT_USE**')**